# Capitalisation after e.g. in a dotpoint list

Tags: punctuation

I am confused how I should treat capitalisation in the following cases:

**Example 1**

Include the following themes in your writing:

- respect, e.g. students must respect their teachers.

Q1: Should "students" start with a capital letter (note it is a complete sentence).

**Example 2**

There are many types of punctuations:

- full stop ends a sentence, e.g. the dog belongs to my neighbour.

Q2: Should "the" start with a capital letter (note it is a complete sentence).

Finally,

Q3: Should the list start with a capital letter (e.g. Respect or Full stop) and end with a full stop.

Comment: Q3 is a duplicate, please follow the link. Q1 and Q2 are general reference (Q1: no, you do not capitalize random words in the middle of a sentence, Q2: yes, the whole example sentence should be in quotes and the *the* should be capitalized). Stack Exchange works best when you limit your questions to one question per question, and when you search the site before asking. Thank you.

Comment: Agree with Reg. The first word is always capitalised and afterwords only special words.
"Respect, e.g. students must respect their teachers."